# How to compare minimised JS files with very long lines? diff prints whole lines which is unreadable (400k characters per line)

Tags: diff, javascript

I need to compare two "minimised", very similar JavaScript files.  Minimisation means that (among other things) newline and space characters that are not needed for interpretation by a computer are removed.  The files therefore have lines up to >400000 characters per line. I do not maintain these files and cannot change that they are minimised.

How can I `diff` / show the differences between these very similar files, only showing the changed/added words, perhaps with 10 characters of context?

Environment:

This is on a server so I cannot install special tools or software for this comparison and we need to work with standard "onboard" tools please.  It is a CentOS server so we have `gawk`, POSIX/GNU tools etc. as well as perl, php and python.  It's just that I cannot install a package or clone a big git repo for this simple task.

We use the `tcsh` for most of our work so if the Answer could work without the special syntax of particular, other shells that would preferable as it would make the solution more easily accessible.

Comment: `fold` them over 80 chars and then `diff`? Minimised files are largely gobbledegook anyways, some random line breaks won't hurt much. Also: why not "serve" these files over your intranet to your workstations and then do your comparison with better tools there?

Comment: The folding might shift differences across line breaks so that only the first change is visible? I cannot easily serve them and hope for a binary diff or something, I know I have seen such a diff command before...

Comment: Why would only the first change be visible? Anyway, why not try it out?

Comment: "standard 'onboard' tools": for what OS? Please remember to always mention your oS when asking questions. You also mentioned in a comment that you don't want to use bash syntax like `<()`. If you're only working with POSIX sh, we need to know it. Please add all such restrictions to the question so people don't waste your time, or theirs, on answers that won't help.

Comment: "_This is on a server so I cannot install special tools or software for this comparison_" - if you need tools for a job then ask the system administrators to install them for you. Or apply to your Change Board. It should be unlikely they will stop you doing your job, but they might suggest alternative solutions

Comment: @muru The second change could be broken across lines and `diff` only compares lines.

Comment: @Ned64 but one of those lines would still be different, no?

Comment: @muru If change #1 adds or removes characters (mod line length) then every line from there on will be different, no matter what.

Comment: @Ned64 true, but what do you mean by "The second change could be broken across lines"?

Comment: @muru Perhaps I was unclear - sorry! - , but in effect we can only detect one change. I need to detect all without false positives.

Answer (score 0):

You can add some whitespace to make it more readable to `diff`. For example, add a new line after all closing brackets and semicolons. That might be enough for you. A quick and dirty `sed` line to do that could be: `sed 's/\([;}]\)/\1\n/g'`.

So, for example for a minified version of jquery hosted at cloudflare.com:

```
curl https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js | sed 's/\([;}]\)/\1\n/g'
```

If you'd rather use some other tool and get a better, more readable script (note that variable name packing for example cannot be undone) there are some options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822119/tool-to-unminify-decompress-javascript).

Comment: OK, how can I use this to diff two local files with no temporary files? Ideally without bash-syntax like `<(`...

Comment: That's an unrelated question, you hadn't said anything about not being able to use temporary files. I'd move them to another system and diff them, but if you really need to solve that part, I suggest you open a new question or at least specify that requirement in the original post.

Comment: If it needs temp files so be it. However, the question was always how to diff two local files.

Comment: Also, added details in the Question, thanks for pointing that out.